# C++ map questions about syntax

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to learning more about maps in general:
i have never seen syntax like this before:
charMap[c]++;
i assume it is adding a char into as key? and incrementing the count as value?  Would someone be able to provide where i can see this notation?  I cant seem to find any information of this.

```
int firstUniqChar(string s) {
    unordered_map<char, int> charMap;
    for (char c : s)
        charMap[c]++;            
}
```

Also I was wondering, how come i receive an error when I try to insert into map but it works when i do map?

```
int firstUniqChar(string s) {
    map<string,int> myMap;

    for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
       auto it = myMap.insert({s[i],1});
        if(!it.second){
            it.first->second+=1;      
        }

    }
    auto itr = myMap.begin();
    while(itr!=myMap.end()){

        cout<<it->first;
        it++;
    }

}
```

Comment: _Are_ you trying to create a `string` out of `s[i]` (which is a `char`) and map it to the _value_ `1` in the second part of your code? If so, I can remove part of my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
unordered_map<char, int> charMap;
charMap[c]++;
```

[std::map::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

So `charMap[c]` returns a reference to the mapped `int` that is increased with `++`.

```
auto it = myMap.insert({s[i], 1});
```

There's no matching [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) overload. Try using [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
auto it = myMap.emplace(s[i], 1);
```

Edit: I just noticed that you changed to a `map` with a `string` as key in your second part of the code and that you probably try to create a `string` from the `char` `s[i]` with length `1` when you do `{s[i],1}`, but that's the wrong way around. The count comes first, then the `char` - it also lacks the *value* part.

Using `insert` it could look like below. I'm using structured bindings to make it easier to see what's what.

```
map<string,int> myMap;

for(size_t i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
   // create a string of length 1 mapped to the value 1
   auto [it, inserted] = myMap.insert({{1, s[i]}, 1});
   auto& [key, value] = *it;
   if(inserted == false) {
       ++value;
   }
}
```